Why the key After performing automount?
I want to make an automatic backup to a flash drive after auto-mounting it.
To do this, I wrote in /etc/fstab...
UUID=0698-A3CF  /flash  vfat  noauto,nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=15,x-systemd.device-timeout=15

And in /etc/systemd/system/ I created the my_backup.service unit. I filled it out according to these instructions.
[Unit]
Description=My backup script trigger
Requires=flash.automount
After=flash.automount

[Service]
ExecStart=/myfolder/python_backup.py

[Install]
WantedBy=flash.automount

The Python script works great if I run it separately and almost perfectly if I run it by mounting a flash drive. Almost, except... actually copying the necessary files. The log says “No /flash device”. In addition, by commenting out the functions for working with files, using a delay in the Python script and the ls /flash command, I found out that the flash drive is not mounted until the script is completed to the end. But the unit says “After”! Is it possible to rewrite the unit so that the Python script starts executing after mounting the flash drive?

When you use x-systemd.automount mount option in your setup, the systemd-fstab-generator generates two units:

flash.mount to do the actual mounting
flash.automount to intercept any requests to the /flash directory, and start the flash.mount unit while holding those requests in wait.

Note that there is nothing that would imply making a mount attempt when a filesystem with the specified UUID appears to the system - only that whenever someone or something tries to access the /flash directory, the system will attempt to mount that filesystem first before allowing that access to proceed.
The flash.automount unit will execute immediately to set up the interception, and its completion does not mean the actual mount has happened yet - in fact, the USB may not be even plugged in yet at that point. Also, the automount unit will only start once, no matter how many times the actual mount will happen, so your script tracks the wrong startup condition.
Since you want the service to run after the actual mount is done, you will need to specify After=flash.mount, not After=flash.automount.
You may also need to specify Type=oneshot in the [Service] section of your my_backup.service, to avoid the service being marked as "failed" once the script completes.
If you have something that would automatically "poke" the /flash mount point as soon as the USB stick is inserted, the above might be all you need. But if there is no such impulse from elsewhere, your service will also need a BindsTo= and After= dependencies to a *.device unit representing the flash drive.
Unfortunately, the default *.device names for USB storage devices tend to be monstrosities like this:
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb2-2\x2d7-2\x2d7:1.0-host6-target6:0:0-6:0:0:3-block-sdf.device

And since the name includes the USB device path, the name will vary if the user won't always plug the flash drive in the same USB port. (Run systemctl without any parameters to see a list of all active units, including the various device units.)
So, you may have to write an udev rule that sets a suitable ENV{SYSTEMD_ALIAS}+= to the backup flash drive, so that you can easily have your service's dependencies refer to it.
The rule might be something like this (disclaimer: not tested):
ACTION="add", SUBSYSTEM="block", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}="0698-A3CF", ENV{SYSTEMD_ALIAS}+="sys-subsystem-usb-storage-devices-backupdrive.device"

In human terms: "when a block device with a filesystem UUID 0698-A3CF is added to the system, also give it a systemd unit alias sys-subsystem-usb-storage-devices-backupdrive.device so other things can be configured to depend on it by that name."

I change .automount to .mount but there is a problem. Automount make mount every time when something needs my usb flash drive. Thus, inserting a flash drive does not lead to a correct backup. And the subsequent command ls /flash, which causes the unit to restart, leads.

x-systemd.automount is automount on access (e.g. ls /flash). It will not automount on flash drive plug-in.

However, when I insert the flash drive, I see (from the LEDs on the Orange Pi One) that my Python script is running - except for operations with /flash, of course.

Then, I think something else is doing the initial access which triggers the mount - and your x-systemd.idle-timeout=15 will keep the flash drive mounted for at least 15 seconds, or longer if something keeps accessing the flash drive. I don't know what that something else might be.
